# Quartz @DisallowConcurrentExecution annotation does not seem to be working

Tags: java, quartz-scheduler

I have a Quartz job that is set to run every periodically. However I want to prevent concurrent executions of this job. I added the @DisallowConcurrentExecution annotation to the class representing this job, but that does not seem to be having any effect.

Here's how I created the job and trigger to store into a JDBC store. The trigger is set to run once every 5 seconds.

```
    JobKey jobKey = new JobKey("sample_job", "default_group");
    String triggerIdentity = jobKey.getName() + "_trigger";
    Scheduler scheduler = StdSchedulerFactory.getDefaultScheduler();
    if (!scheduler.checkExists(jobKey)) {

        JobDetail jobDetail = JobBuilder.newJob(SampleJob.class).withIdentity(jobKey).build();
        Trigger trigger = newTrigger()
            .withIdentity(triggerIdentity, jobKey.getGroup())
            .startAt(new Date())
            .withSchedule(simpleSchedule()
            .withIntervalInSeconds(5)
            .repeatForever())
            .build();
        scheduler.scheduleJob(jobDetail, trigger);

    }
    scheduler.start();
```

Here is the sample job class that I created. It basically sets off a timer that finishes in 10 seconds and prints a message.

```
@DisallowConcurrentExecution
public class SampleJob implements Job {

    public SampleJob() {
    }

    @Override
    public void execute(JobExecutionContext jobExcutionContext) {

        final Date now = new Date();
        System.out.println("Starting sample job: " + now);
        Timer t = new Timer();
        t.schedule(new TimerTask() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                System.out.println("Done: " + now);
                this.cancel();
            }
        }, 10000L);

    }
}
```

When I run this I see the following output, which to me suggests that the job is triggering off every 5 seconds even though the previous execution has not yet completed. Am I misinterpreting the meaning of the @DisallowConcurrentExecution or is my test incorrect?

```
Starting sample job: Sat Apr 04 22:45:06 EDT 2015
Starting sample job: Sat Apr 04 22:45:11 EDT 2015
Done: Sat Apr 04 22:45:01 EDT 2015
Starting sample job: Sat Apr 04 22:45:16 EDT 2015
Done: Sat Apr 04 22:45:06 EDT 2015
Starting sample job: Sat Apr 04 22:45:21 EDT 2015
Done: Sat Apr 04 22:45:11 EDT 2015
Done: Sat Apr 04 22:45:16 EDT 2015
Starting sample job: Sat Apr 04 22:45:26 EDT 2015
Starting sample job: Sat Apr 04 22:45:31 EDT 2015
Done: Sat Apr 04 22:45:21 EDT 2015
```

Answer (score 0):

Turns out I was overthinking the problem. A Timer seems like its run off a separate thread. So as far as the job is concerned, it is completed before the timer is finished. A simple Thread.sleep(10000) instead of the Timer did the trick.